# Why is parcel watch not detecting changes other than in my package.json?

Tags: npm, watch, parceljs

I'm using parcel 2.0.1.

Package.json configuration looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "appbuild": "parcel build repo/someFile.ts repo/someOtherFile.ts repo/thirdFileToWatch.ts repo/4thFileToWatch --dist-dir dist",
    "appwatch": "parcel watch repo/someFile.ts repo/someOtherFile.ts repo/thirdFileToWatch.ts repo/4thFileToWatch --dist-dir dist"
  }
```

Upon *npm run appwatch*, the desired files are built and the result is in dist folder. Which is fine, but changing (for example) someFile.ts after it does nothing.

It looks as if watch was still running, but the build only happens once...**except if I make a change in package.json**. Than I can see some action in console and the message about successful build. How can I make watch detect every change in those 4 files listed in command + their imports (recursively)?

The result is the same if run from Task Runner explorer in VS or console.